# Permanent mount volume via sshfs Sierra

Tags: macos-sierra, sshfs, automount

I am trying to permanently mount a volume via `sshfs` on `mac`. I have tried to follow the instructions in [how-to-get-automount-and-sshfs-osxfuse-working-with-yosemite](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/159316/how-to-get-automount-and-sshfs-osxfuse-working-with-yosemite) (Although I have `Sierra`, I couldn't find instructions for it so I thought to give it a try with `Yosemite` instructions). However I get stuck at this step:

> If you do not see `mount_sshfs`, then you need to do this step. This
>   is a critical step because it is easily forgotten and may create
>   headaches. `sudo ln -s $(which sshfs) /sbin/mount_sshfs`.

Here is the error:

```
$ sudo ln -s $(which sshfs) /sbin/mount_sshfs
ln: /sbin/mount_sshfs: Operation not permitted
```

I couldn't find the way to solve this.

Comment: Apple has locked down the OS in Sierra. Even sudo su does not work.  Makes one wonder why apple still calls it sudo??? Why have sudo at all...

Answer (score 1):

Apple protects some critical folders by "System Integrity Protection (SIP)", you can temporarily disable it with the instructions given here 
https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/208478/how-do-i-disable-system-integrity-protection-sip-aka-rootless-on-macos-os-x